# C# split string on X number of alpha numeric values

Tags: c#

this might be simple question I have 3 strings

A123949DADWE2ASDASDW
ASDRWE234DS2334234234
ZXC234ASD43D33SDF23SDF

I want to split those by the first 8 characters and then the 10th and 11th and then combine them into one string.

So I would get:
A123949DWE
ASDRWE23S2
ZXC234AS3D

Basically the 9th character and anything after the 12th character is removed.

Comment: This would obviously be completely trivial with a for loop or a couple of `string.Substring` calls.  Is there something more you are looking for?

Comment: Your example result seems to take the 11th and 12th characters, skipping both the 9th and 10th character. Which is correct: the question wording, or the expected result?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904308.aspx):

```
s = s.Substring(0, 8) + s[10] + s[11]
```

Example code:

```
string[] a = {
                 "A123949DADWE2ASDASDW",
                 "ASDRWE234DS2334234234",
                 "ZXC234ASD43D33SDF23SDF"
             };

a = a.Select(s => s.Substring(0, 8) + s[10] + s[11]).ToArray();
```

Result:

```
A123949DWE
ASDRWE23S2
ZXC234AS3D
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's say you have them declared as string variables:

```
string s1 = "A123949DADWE2ASDASDW";
string s2 = "ASDRWE234DS2334234234";
string s3 = "ZXC234ASD43D33SDF23SDF";
```

You can use the substring to get what you want:

```
string s1substring = s1.Substring(0,8) + s1.Substring(9,2);
string s2substring = s1.Substring(0,8) + s1.Substring(9,2);
string s3substring = s1.Substring(0,8) + s1.Substring(9,2);
```

And that should give you what you need. Just remember, that the string position is zero-based so you'll have to subtract one from the starting position.

Answer (score 0):

So you could do:

```
string final1 = GetMyString("A123949DADWE2ASDASDW");
string final2 = GetMyString("ASDRWE234DS2334234234");
string final3 = GetMyString("ZXC234ASD43D33SDF23SDF");

public function GetMyString(string Original)
{
    string result = Original.Substring(12);
    result = result.Remove(9, 1);
    return result;
}
```